# Plot grouped bar graph from CSV in R

Tags: r, csv, plot

I have this dataset (https://www.dropbox.com/s/c1e81dzquv2j10j/day.csv?dl=0). I need to plot a grouped bar graph of the mean and the standard deviation of variable 'cnt', but these values should be grouped by the variable 'season'. I loaded the file from CSV as follows:

```
data <- read.csv(file="/Users/rafaame/Downloads/Bike-Sharing-Dataset/day.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",")
```

How would you plot it? Thanks.

Comment: Try to give some more information and a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). The code you provide does not say anything about your data. No one is probably able to help you without knowing how your data are like.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this??

[image]

```
data  <- read.csv("day.csv")
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data,aes(x=season,y=cnt))+
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean,geom="bar",fill="lightgreen",color="grey50")+
  stat_summary(fun.data="mean_sdl",mult=1,geom="errorbar",width=.1,color="red")
```